# How to make 'ip link' settings persistent

Tags: linux

I'm turning off the spoof checking for a specific virtual interface on my Linux box. However this setting is not persistent after a reboot. How can I make it persistent?

From my understanding ip settings should be persistent per se. Am I missing something?

I'm using this command to turn off spoof checking:

`ip link set <interface-name> vf <vf-number> spoof off`

After running the command I can verify that spoof checking is off:

`vf 10 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto`

However after a reboot I can see it being turned on again.

Comment: Actually `ip` settings are just “live” configurations: they are always lost on reboot. However, there are ways to make them automatically loaded on boot but the way to do it depends on your specific distribution and what kind of network manager it uses

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7.6. 
I tried adding the 'ip link set' command into /etc/rc.d/rc.local
After a reboot the spoof is still in its default settings.
I also ensured that rc.local has execution permissions.

Comment: Sorry I'm not CentOS nor RedHat expert so I can't advise you precisely. As general hints I can tell that it might be because the rc.local file actually does not get executed; or it does get executed, but before the network manager which thus overwrites your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a custom shell script on the system that does ip related changes and that gets executed after each reboot. I simply added the ip link at the bottom and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I would run the command at startup, depending on your Linux version there's usually a method to run custom commands at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Using Network Manager should make this persistent:

```
$ nmcli conn modify <interface-name> sriov.vfs '<vf-number> trust=true spoof-check=false’
```

I don't have any NIC which supports this currently, but the syntax seems to check out.